# Нужно найти символы '-' , '_' , '' в строке и их удалить, объединить все слова и сделать, чтобы они были с большой буквы

Tags: php

input :  The workers quitting over return-to-office
output : TheWorkersQuittingOverReturnToOffice
Вот моё решение, не работающее :

```
function separeted(string $input){
if ($input < 0) {
    return null;
};
$chars = ['_', '-', ' '];
str_replace($chars, '', $input);
```

}

Comment: ```return str_replace($chars, '', $input);```. Что по вашему происходит вот тут? ```($input < 0)``` подозреваю что совсем не то что вы хотите...

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'The workers quitting over return-to-office output';
$str = preg_replace('/[-_]/', ' ', $str);
$str = ucwords($str);
$str = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
echo $str;
```